# Durandal 2.0: transition not triggered while staying on same view with new data

Tags: durandal

Here's my shell:

```
<div>
    <div id="content" class="container-fluid page-host main">
        <!--ko router: { transition:'entrance', alwaysTriggerAttach: 'true', cacheViews: 'true' }--><!--/ko-->
    </div>
</div>
```

I always navigate to views using:

```
router.navigate(route);
```

Now, when being on a certain view (item), and calling the navigate function for another id (/#item/id), the data changes correctly, but the transition does not happen.

Any advice?
Thanks

Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

Should transition be triggered is defined in this function of durandal/js/composition.js:

```
function shouldTransition(context) {
if (system.isString(context.transition)) {
    if (context.activeView) {
        if (context.activeView == context.child) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!context.child) {
            return true;
        }

        if (context.skipTransitionOnSameViewId) {
            var currentViewId = context.activeView.getAttribute('data-view');
            var newViewId = context.child.getAttribute('data-view');
            return currentViewId != newViewId;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

return false;
```

If you want to trigger transition then navigating within the same view, you can comment this if statement:

```
if (context.activeView == context.child) {
   return false;
```